# Unhandled exception at 0x00000000772CA267 (ntdll.dll) in *****.exe : 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFFFFFCA800000000

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-studio-debugging, winhttp

I am getting this exception

> Unhandled exception at 0x00000000772CA267 (ntdll.dll) in ******.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFFFFFCA800000000.

When I look into callstack I don't see my code in the stack but the below:

```
ntdll.dll!RtlFreeHeap() Unknown
kernel32.dll!HeapFree() Unknown
winhttp.dll!CAuthData::Clear(void)  Unknown
winhttp.dll!HTTP_USER_REQUEST::_AdjustCredentialStates(unsigned short,int *)    Unknown
winhttp.dll!HTTP_USER_REQUEST::_ResponseProcessingLoop(class PENDING_API_CALL *)    Unknown
winhttp.dll!HTTP_USER_REQUEST::OnRecvResponse(unsigned long)    Unknown
winhttp.dll!WEBIO_REQUEST::OnIoComplete(unsigned long,unsigned __int64,class HTTP_ASYNC_OVERLAPPED *)   Unknown
winhttp.dll!HTTP_THREAD_POOL::_WorkItemCallback(void)   Unknown
ntdll.dll!TppWorkpExecuteCallback() Unknown
ntdll.dll!TppWorkerThread() Unknown
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()  Unknown
```

We use SOAP req/res. But we have updated couple of req/res to REST not we use json req/res. After this change we get the above problem. Sometimes everything works fine You could say failure is 50% times.

Comment: You need to debug your code. Something has gone wrong in the code you didn't post here, maybe a buffer overflow somewhere, `ntdll.dll!RtlFreeHeap()` suggests this..

Comment: Your code appears to have corrupted the heap

Comment: I get only above callstack from VS

Comment: Any technique/tool to figure out where the bufferoverflow happened?

Comment: faster of all you corrupt heap before this and on another thread. this is stack of working thread, where no your code at all. you need search in another place

Comment: `TppWorkerThread` - this is worker thread from system thread pool. it execute *winhttp* library callback. (`WEBIO_REQUEST::OnIoComplete`) - here no your code and errors. heap already corrupted in another place

Comment: @VivekYadav these bugs are hard to find. You could try blindly to double the required size for all your memory allocations (roughly replace all `malloc(x)` by `malloc(x * 2)`). If the problem goes away, reverse all of those modifications one by one until the problem occurs again. Now you have more or less pinpointed the relevant code. Now check that code.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. We have large codebase and many of the places I am not aware also we have our own wrapper functions. It seems I have to investigate deeper.

Comment: It has very random behaviour. Sometimes it works flawless and sometimes it fails at different points in the windows system dlls. Any guesses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for this problem. Actually before this call there was bufferoverflow which was corrupting my heap. Fixing the bufferoverflow solved my problem.